# Why Logger not logged??

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

This is my `Log4j` config file:

```
<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.security">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

.

And I use a logge into a service for example, like this:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommessaServiceImpl.class);
```

and then:

```
LOG.info("Start method");
```

But I can see nothing about it into my console...

Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are logging `info`(LOG.info) and logging level is set to `error` and `warn`.

Change it to

```
<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons you will not see logs.

1. You have not defined any appenders. You need something like:

   ```
   <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss,SS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
   </appender>
   ```
2. Your log levels are all set to "error" and you are trying to log at the "info" level.